# Does Windows iOT Core provide the normal Api

Tags: win-universal-app, iot

1. Does Windows 10 iOT core provide these Libraries like SMS, GPS, gyrometer as in windows RT8.1 0r Win 10?
2. Can Windows 10 iOT core run win 10 app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows IoT Core runs Universal Windows Platform apps using the Universal API Contract (which includes [Geolocator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.aspx) and [Gyrometer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.gyrometer.aspx) and [ChatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.chat.chatmessage.aspx) classes) as well as IoT specific contracts such as the Low Level Contract (which includes [GPIO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.gpio.aspx), etc.)

See https://dev.windows.com/en-us/iot for more details on Windows IoT.
See [Device Families](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn894631.aspx#device_families) on MSDN for more information about how IoT fits in with other Windows 10 devices.